# Group by a field that does not belongs to the consulted table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query that allows me to group the results by a field that does not belong to the table consulted.

Having the following associations

[image: ER]

In this scenario **tickets** table has a field called status I need to perform a sum over this field and group the result by coordinations name. *Only coordination of users who have tickets*.

I am trying the following query:

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'open' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 'open',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 'in progress',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'closed' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 'closed'
FROM
    tickets t,
    users u,
    user_coordinations uc,
    coordinations c
GROUP BY 1
```

And this is the result i am getting

[image: result]

This result looks like what I expect but does not take into consideration the condition of only taking coordinations of users who have tickets

Please check this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ed08/1

Thanks for your time

*I would like to point out that the answer was already found, using explicit joins solved the problem as I was recommended in the comments, the example in sql fiddle shows the correct query. Thanks for the help.*

Comment: Recommend that you use explicit joins rather than the older style.  You may find your problem immediately solved.

Comment: you should try http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler and post it with some sample data. That way people could help more. So set some tables up with sample data. Then link back a script people can tinker with and try and assist.

Comment: Thanks for the resource

Comment: As @Degan suggested using explicit join is doing the work.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: First of all, use a proper join.  The second thing, your query will return Carterian products of the 4 tables since you don't have join condition.

Comment: I take it you solved this now? since the SQLFiddle now does inner joins with tickets as the primary table to join off. I always look at diagrams here when working out the type of join I want https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp