# Translate MYSQL query to HQL using multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, hql, grails-orm

everyone.

I am using grails 3.3.0.M2 framework with mysql as data-source the following sql query is working as expected

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'open' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 'open',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 'in progress',
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'closed' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 'closed'
FROM
    tickets t
        INNER JOIN
    users u ON t.user_id = u.id
        INNER JOIN
    user_coordinations uc ON uc.user_id = u.id
        INNER JOIN
    coordinations c ON c.id = uc.coordination_id
GROUP BY 1
```

I translated to HQL using implicit JOIN *but I am getting the wrong results*, here is the hql query:

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'open' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'closed' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)
FROM
    Ticket t, User u, UserCoordination uc, Coordination c
WHERE
    MONTH(t.dateCreated) = :month
GROUP BY 1
```

In order to get the right results stack overflow users help me to understand that the query needs to use explicit JOINS, here the question: [Group by a field that does not belongs to the consulted table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958925/group-by-a-field-that-does-not-belongs-to-the-consulted-table)

Right now I am trying with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'open' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END),
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'closed' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END)
FROM
    Ticket t
        INNER JOIN
    User u
        INNER JOIN
    UserCoordination uc
        INNER JOIN
    Coordination c
WHERE
    MONTH(t.dateCreated) = :month
GROUP BY 1
```

But i am getting a *com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException* with the caused message **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join user_coordinations usercoordi2_ on inner join coordinations coordinat' at line 1**

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT new map(
    c.name as name,
(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'open' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) as open,
(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) as pending, 
(CASE
        WHEN t.status = 'closed' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) as closed,
    SUM(open) as openSum,
    SUM(pending) as pendingSum,
    SUM(closed) as closedSum
)
FROM
    Ticket t
        left join t.user u left join u.userCoordination uc left join uc.coordination c 
WHERE
    MONTH(t.dateCreated) = :month
```

//GROUP BY 1

What you had had lots missing above is more like what you need, you need 
`select new map(i.item as item...` if you compare the basics of this with what you had and what i tried to do you can see why you had errors.

unsure about your group by it should be group by something. Wasn't sure by inner join if you just meant a join if that was the case leave out all the left join since left join attempts to connect and get any null hasMany relations etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering @vahid. `SELECT NEW ...` is new for me. I can see the advantages in the construction of the query. About the question I am getting a _org.hibernate.QueryException_ with the caused message: _could not resolve property: userCoordination of: ni.edu.ucc.leon.User_

Comment: I think this is because there is a one to many association between User and Coordination. How can i express this in the query? There is a SQL Fiddle in this location: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ed08/1

Comment: @yuor first question you have `UserCoordination` I have no idea what your domain object mapping for it is. so if `User hasMany = [ ucord:UserCoordination]` the that would be `left join u.ucord uc`  it is what ever you have declared the mapping as in your domain object. In regards to your 2nd question one to many is catered for by `left join` where something is null or something has some value this will capture all.   If you leave out the `left` word from `join` then it will list 1 record for it. So when left join and user1 has two of the many records it will appear twice

Comment: My mistake @vadin it is a _many to many association between User and Coordination_. So _UserCoordination is the pivot table_. Thats why I am getting the error in `u.UserCoordination`. I am sorry I did not explain myself correctly

Comment: I don't think that matters, pay attention to camel case  `u.UserCoordination` vs  `u.userCoordination`  I had deliberately made the mistake / distinction in the answer given since I can't see how you have declared  your relationship. If you  have  `hasMany = [ userCoordination:UserCoordination]` then the correct is the latter of the vs  above

Comment: In this scenario the Entity UserCoordination is created by hand because I need to add some custom properties to it to the pivotal entity. So User and Coordination Entities have no reference to UserCoordination. In UserCooridnation are declared the properties `User user` and `Coordination coordination` plus some properties

Comment: well then this question is all wrong simply because HibernateQueryLanguage is going to query your data using hibernate. If it is not mapped in your domain classes then HQL is no good to you. Try http://mrhaki.blogspot.co.uk/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-groovy-sql.html and you should then be able to run your original sql queyr directly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148736/discussion-between-user615274-and-vahid).